# Unable to create setup file for C# WinForm Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to create setup file of my C# WinForm Application, for that I'm referring [this](http://www.thecodekey.com/Articles/C_VB/Create_Setup_in_Windows_Application.aspx) article, please see the ***5th step***, after selecting ***Setup and Deployment option*** following window gets open

[image: Expected],

but in my case when I select Setup and Deployment option the following window gets open

[image]

i.e. I'm not able to see any option like "Setup Project", "Web Setup Project".... I'm strange why it happening, please help.. Thank you..!

Comment: What kind of visual studio do you have ?

Comment: If you are using **visual studio 2012** then you will not see those options.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey mate you can find what you need under `Setup and Deployment` item, just click on the arrow header and you ll find what you need. Like this :

[image]